# Why the angle between incident ray and normal is 0° and not 180° if incident ray is directed perpendicular to "plane" of plane mirror?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]
Here the incident ray is normal to the *plane* of plane mirror, that is obvious but why everybody say that this ray is making an angle 0° with normal, why the angle is not 180° ? Are they relating it like vectors that the smallest angle between two vectors is taken as the angle between the two vectors ?

Comment: In ray optics one typically doesn't consider the normal as a vector, they implicitly mean the line parallel to the vector, because the sign of the normal is irrelevant for the physics. Working with the angle $0^{\circ}$ is simply more convenient, and again, doesn't change any predictions.

Comment: So what is the orientation of normal, that people use to find angle between it and incident ray?

Comment: The definition of these angle values predated the modern conception of vectors. People simply didn't think of things that way.

Comment: Do you wanna ask normal is vector or scalar ? @Phasor